# Design view not appearing in xamarin .axml

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Why don't I have the option to switch between source and design view in this intro xamarin app? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had opened the folder in Visual Studio rather than the solution. After opening the .sln in in solution explorer the designer appeared.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark your answer after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.